# Partial function application with the original docstring in Python?

Tags: python, partial-application

For [partial function application](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partial_application), I know there are several ways to do that in Python. However, they seems not to preserve the original function's docstring.

Take `functools.partial` as example:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(a, b, c=1):
    """Return (a+b)*c."""
    return (a+b)*c

bar10_p = partial(foo, b=10)
print bar10_p.__doc__

partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application 
of the given arguments and keywords.
```

Let's try [fn.py](https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py):

```
from fn import F

def foo(a, b, c=1):
    """Return (a+b)*c."""
    return (a+b)*c

bar10_F = F(foo, b=10)
print bar10_F.__doc__

Provide simple syntax for functions composition
(through << and >> operators) and partial function
application (through simple tuple syntax).

Usage example:

>>> func = F() << (_ + 10) << (_ + 5)
>>> print(func(10))
25
>>> func = F() >> (filter, _ < 6) >> sum
>>> print(func(range(10)))
15
```

Is there any Python package/module providing partial application with preserved docstring?

### UPDATE

As [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340389/kevin) and [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) mentioned, the function signature has changed such that it is not suggested to stick to the original function's docstring. I realized that I'm looking for an updated docstring with something like `foo() with a default b value of 10` (Thanks for Kevin's simple but direct example.).

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the docstring?  The parameters have changed, so the original docstring will be incorrect or misleading.  You should probably just write a new one via `bar10_F.__doc__ = ...`.

Comment: You are right. I should update my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`__doc__` is writable, on `partial` objects as well as on functions; simply copy it over:

```
bar10_p = partial(foo, b=10)
bar10_p.__doc__ = func.__doc__
```

or use the [`functools.update_wrapper()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) to do the copying for you; it'll copy a few other pieces of metadata for you too:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

bar10_p = partial(foo, b=10)
update_wrapper(bar10_p, foo)
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage this.  The partial object has a different signature from the original, so the copied docstring will mislead.  `update_wrapper()` is even worse because (I think?) it will make `help()` and `inspect` lie about the signature.

Comment: @Kevin: yet `functools.wraps()` is widely used for decorators that also can change the signature. The docstring does not necessarily dictate the signature of the function! This depends *heavily* on the actual contents of the docstring.

Comment: They *can* change the signature, but that doesn't mean they should.

Comment: @Kevin: as such, 'strongly discouraging' is a rather heavy handed response here.

Comment: If I'm reading your nicely-formatted API reference docs, and I'm told the `foo()` function takes two arguments, I expect to pass it two arguments.  If I get a `TypeError: too many arguments`, I will be rather confused.

Comment: @Kevin: doesn't that make assumptions about the docstrings for the callables the OP is wrapping that we cannot make? That's what introspection is for (which `help()` does, it includes the actual signature of the callable).

Comment: A docstring will document all parameters, assuming it's properly written.

Comment: @Kevin: There is a risk with any proxy not quite reflecting the underlying item quite correctly. That doesn't mean that all proxying should therefor be avoided.

Comment: @Kevin: that is a style choice, not a choice made by the Python language. In practice this is not true. To dismiss copying a docstring across because in an ideal world docstrings should document all arguments is rather overzealous.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a new `__doc__`.

```
bar10_p = partial(foo, b=10)
bar10_p.__doc__ = """foo() with a default b value of 10.

See foo().

"""
```

Your function has a different interface from the original, so it should not copy the docstring exactly.

Answer (score 3):

With [`makefun`](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun) you can do it:

```
from makefun import partial

def foo(a, b, c=1):
    """Return (a+b)*c."""
    return (a + b) * c

bar10_p = partial(foo, b=10)

assert bar10_p(0) == 10
assert bar10_p(0, c=2) == 20 
help(bar10_p)
```

It yields:

```
Help on function foo in module makefun.tests.test_so:

foo(a, c=1)
    <This function is equivalent to 'foo(a, c=1, b=10)', see original 'foo' doc below.>
    Return (a+b)*c.
```

Note that if you have any comment on how the docstring should be updated, do not hesitate to propose an issue on the git repo !

(I'm the author by the way)

Answer (score 2):

Partial has access to `func` method which is the original function. So through original function, you have access to original function docstring.

Try this:

```
from math import cos
from functools import partial

cos_partial = partial(cos, 0.5)
print(cos_partial.func.__doc__)
```